# error with rostopic echo -p

Tags: ros, rostopic, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

After upgrading to Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, I'm having issues saving rostopic data to a .csv using the '-p' option.

The topics echo and bag fine, but when I try to out it into plot friendly format it gives me this error (up to about 20 times):

```
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 940, in callback
    self.suffix + '\n')
TypeError: _str_plot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value_transform'
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks,

Andrew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247276/error-with-rostopic-echo--p/) by [alewi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28299/alewi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-11-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dseifert](https://answers.ros.org/users/24478/dseifert/) on 2016-11-09**:
Same issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug that was addressed in https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/915 and should be fixed in ros-kinetic-ros-comm 1.12.6

---

Originally posted by [dseifert](https://answers.ros.org/users/24478/dseifert/) with karma: 106 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1